# How to interpret glmer in repeated measures experiments?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

My current design is that for each subject, there are two conditions. For each condition, there are 60 trials with some slight randomization. We measure the subject response (which also binomial) for each trial. Ultimately we want to test the behavioral difference between these two manipulated conditions.

Currently, I am using:

```
glmer(response ~ condition + (1|ID), data = df, family = "binomial")
```

I want to see if different conditions can signifcanly influence the behaviors. I did not got significant p-value with linear regression (which took average score for each subject in each condition). But the p-value is significant if I include every single trial in this model. I am wondering how to explain this. Does this action of utilizing all single trials add the possibility of false positive?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you decided to average over trials (within condition) in your initial analysis instead of using all individual trials?

Comment: Maybe you had a huge variation within an individual between trials which you were masking by averaging them, i.e. low responses would "cancel" high ones.

Comment: Bc in this type of experiment we usually start from t-test, that requires averaged within each condition. Then I tried linear regression, which also requires averaging. But then I realized since the response are not balanced, it might make more sense to consider each trial? But I don't have much experience analysing repeated measures data, so I'm not sure.

Comment: I see. Well, from an outside perspective I'd use a multilevel model with all trials, but I think whether this is a good idea is a subject knowledge question, so you need to consider it in the context of your field of study.